# How to eliminate the effect of a categorical variable in sparse data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, predictor

I have data from many individuals. For each individual I have a predictor variable $D$ and a response variable $C$ which are continuous. Below I have plotted simulated data for three individuals. Every individual has a different sampling of $D$. I want to model the underlying relationship between $D$ and $C$ while removing the effects of individual (categorical). Matlab is preferred, when possible.

Thank you.

[image: data]

EDIT: Below is a more realistic simulated dataset of 40 individuals.
In these data, each individual has between 1 and 5 values of $C$, where $C =  3*exp(-.01*D) + c$ where $c$ is a randomized constant. I think what I want to do is regenerate the exponential function (and its coefficients) from the data and then estimate $c$ for each individual.

```
[F,G] = fit(allD,allC,'exp1');%matlab
```

Yields the exponential function but I am not sure how to recover the $c$. It is not the residuals.

[image: data2]

Comment: What do you think you should do?

Comment: My naive solution would be to pool all the measurements together and fit a single curve to that. But I am almost certain that there are better solutions.

Comment: Why does the title say sparse? What is sparse?

Comment: For a particular value of D, I am very unlikely to have samples from more than one individual. For some individuals I will have insufficient samples to accurately represent a curve. But across all individuals, I will have a comprehensive sampling.

Comment: Is your response non-negative? And is the expected scatter for a category independent of $D$? (e.g. in many cases, the "one category model" might be fit to $\log{C}$, to account for non-negative response and constant %-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the proper technique used for this kind of analysis: nonlinear mixed-effects estimation.

```
% matlab
mdl = @(PHI,D) PHI(1)*exp(PHI(2)*D)+PHI(3);
phi0 = [3 .01 0];
[beta,PSI,stats,B] = nlmefitsa(allD,allC,categorical(allS),[],mdl,phi0,...
  'OptimFun','fminunc','Vectorization','SingleGroup','LogLikMethod','none');
plot(B(3,:) ,c,'.')
plot([-.5 .5],[-.5 .5],'k')
```

The fixed effects (effects of $D$) is found in beta and the random effects (effects of individual) are found in B. This method seems to fail when the number of individuals and/or measurements per individual are low. One reason I am starting with simulated data is to estimate how much data I will need to collect to isolate the individual effects from the population effects for a given sparsity of measurements.  Below I have plotted the estimated vs true effect of subject for a simulated data set consisting of 200 individuals, each with between 20-30 measurements.

I hope this is useful to others, and that there are not too many errors of vocabulary.

[image: simfit]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to run a panel regression like:

$$ y_{it} = b_0 + b_1 x_{it} + b_2 x_{it}^2 + u_i + \epsilon_{it}$$

Where $u_i$ are either category specific [fixed effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_effects_model) or, if you assume that they're mean zero and uncorrelated with $x$, [random effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model).

You would estimate a curve with different vertical offsets for each category. Notation note: $i$ indexes the category, $t$ indexes an observation within a category.

Answer (score 0):

Given the plot and your question you are trying to unify all the predictor variables into one **predictor** and all the response variables into one **response**

This is possible. Mathematically speaking you want a curve which fits the green,blue and red one.

You can either do this by using the least squares method wherein other curves would serves as residuals.